# Broadcast emergency through non-connected microphones using IoT

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, iot

I'm new to IoT field, i was discussing with my team a solution to broadcast messages and emergency through public institution (School, mosque ...etc) which have microphones some of them are old which don't have any smart or communication layer, and we want to have a solution to connect these Mics in the IoT platform to trigger actions,broadcast.

if anyone aware with these solutions what are the technologies we need or hardware to make these non-connected microphones connected

Thank you

Comment: not aware but none-the-less a very interesting question:  i think its more up to the requirements than to find "something".   How long should it be able to work independently (battery).   what in case of no access to internet, mobile network (big disasters).  how diverse or all the systems to connect to.  are they almost alike and is interfacing easy (just plain audio output)   or do you need to look into every type to get it working.  who is going to test it from time to time to see if it actually works.  how well can these things be protected of misuse etc etc.... very interesting challenge.

Comment: @jcuypers very interesting questions but i think these are advanced question about what we should start with, i'm looking for a proof of concept the clear requirement now is a POC and what technologies and hardware needed, what i've got in mind is the non-smart (dont have IP) should be connected to a device which have IP then we can connect with it through IoT platform, but i have no idea what devices name or technologies i should research to be aware of that